# python script for simple information extraction

Tags: python

I have data of the following form:

```
Overall evaluation: 2
Invite to interview: 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 4
Use or provision of open data (1): 3
Use or provision of open data (2): 2
"Open by default" (1): 3
"Open by default" (2): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 3
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 2
Market opportunity and timing (1): 3
Market opportunity and timing (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (1): 3
Triple bottom line impact (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (3): 3
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 2
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 3
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 2
```

I want to render it as follows:

```
=2+3+3+3+4+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+4+3+2+3+2
```

So far as I know, Python is pretty powerful for this type of silly task, but I'm not very familiar with the syntax, what would be the best way to accomplish this aim?

Maybe something like:

```
#create an array
#array = "="
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    #number = grab that number off the end with some kind of regex
    #array.append(number + "+")
```

Would it be possible to just run this in the python shell and feed in data and then grab out the result?

Comment: Hint use something like `line.split(":")`

Comment: if you know that your number is always going to be single digit on the very end of the line, `line[-1]` will do that for you. else, `re.search('.*\d+,line)` will do the same thing. also, i would suggest (if youre going to just sum it in th end) to initialize array as `array = []` then call `.append(number)` then afterwards just `sum(array)`. a string cannot be appended on unless you do `array += number + '+'

Comment: ah! great! good idea. shit. sometimes I'm really very shortsighted.

Comment: @RNar would this also work in a shell? If I just left the shell open and kept inputting data to that and grabing the result instead of running the short script each time?

Comment: if you want it to work for shell, you would need to add some logic like whether or not you want to read input from a shell or from a file, and if a shell, you would need to learn how to use [`input`](http://sweetme.at/2014/01/22/how-to-get-user-input-from-the-command-line-in-a-python-script/)

Comment: what I mean is like, I open a terminal, type `python`, and then I have that kind of dynamic `>>` program running

Comment: short answer: yes. you would just need to type it line by line. the way the python shell works is that if it reads anything that requires a code block (for/while loops, function defs, etc) then it wont run the code until you input an empty line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        number = int(line.split(':')[1])
        array.append(number)
print '+'.join(array)
```

Basically, use the split function to get the number, and then print it as you wish. Please take care of error handling to check if it is integer or not, or if the line has a : or not

Not sure what you mean by shell, but yes you can make a function, and just call a function:

Comment: would this also work in the shell? just like, leave it open and keep pulling out data, throwing it at the shell, and collecting the result?

Comment: What do you mean by work in the shell? Run it in the python shell, or run it as a shell script?

Comment: i think he means a shell script

Comment: Using `'+'.join(array)` should be better than a for loop. Opening the file with `with open (..) as f:` shoud be better too

Comment: @LoïcG. :/ what do you mean?

Comment: @S.Matthew_English : 
I'm just saying that to display the values of the list separated by a "+", using the `join()` built-in method is better than a for loop